# How do I solve $(1+x^2)y'=\frac{1}{y}, z\geq 0, y(0)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this assignment:

$$(1+x^2)y'=\frac{1}{y}, z\geq 0, y(0)=0$$

There was a long time ago that I solved one of those, but if I remember it right, I would want to rewrite the equation on the formula $$ar^2+br+c$$ so that I can solve it with the pq-formula. In case of that, $\frac{1}{y}$ would be c, but I cant just rewrite that as it is a fraction...? I would like some hints on how to solve this! :)

Comment: Isn't this just separation of variables? And what is variable $z$ in $z \geq 0$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Just rewrite $$(1+x^2)y'=\frac{1}{y}$$ as $$y \space y'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ and now integrate both sides remembering that $(y^2)'=2 y \space y'$.

I am sure that you can take from here.